# Altec Lansing iML 237 not Working in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, sound, usb

I have an Altec Lansing iML 237 external USB that was working in 11.04, but does not in 11.10.  When plugged in, a "CM102-A+/102S+ Audio Controller" appears in the sound system settings, but it will not play.  The only profile setting is "Analog Stereo Output", but the speaker uses a digital interface over USB.

The output of lsusb is:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0d8c:0103 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM102-A+/102S+ Audio Controller
```

The system log when the speaker is plugged in:

```
Oct 31 20:08:26 TOSHIBA-NB505 kernel: [164035.560115] usb 2-2: new full speed USB device number 8 using uhci_hcd
Oct 31 20:08:26 TOSHIBA-NB505 mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2"
Oct 31 20:08:26 TOSHIBA-NB505 mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
```

Any ideas, or is the driver for this device under linux 3.0 broken?

Answer (score 1):

Well, just like when your car stops making that funny noise when you take it to the mechanic, the speaker started working!

I am going to attribute it to the mere action of posting to AskUbuntu!

Comment: Glad its working for you!